# List empty cell numbers in a MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to check empty cells in a range. I need those empty cell numbers to appear in a MsgBox.

```
Sub IsEmptyRange()
Dim cell As Range
Dim bIsEmpty As Boolean

bIsEmpty = False
For Each cell In Range("B1:B19")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        bIsEmpty = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If bIsEmpty = True Then
    MsgBox "There are empty cells in your range"
'I NEED THE EMPTY CELLS TO APPEAR IN THE ABOVE MSGBOX
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nitpick, but you know, that "is" prefix exists to make the variable naturally read like a Boolean. Tacking a "b-for-Boolean" prefix *on top of that* looks kind of weird IMO. Drop Hungarian Notation prefixing, it's useless annoying clutter.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
msgbox Range("B1:B19").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution adapts your code.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim emptyStr As String
emptyStr = ""

For Each cell In Range("B1:B19")
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then _
        emptyStr = emptyStr & cell.Address(0, 0) & ", "
Next cell

If emptyStr <> "" Then MsgBox Left(emptyStr, Len(emptyStr) - 2)
```

If the `cell` is empty, it stores the address in `emptyStr`. The `if` condition can be condensed as `isEmpty` returns a Boolean.

Comment: `Join(Split(cell.Address, "$")` would produce the same result as `Cell.Address(0, 0)`.

Comment: @Variatus; I see - it's not clear in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Sub ListEmptyCells()
    
    Dim Rng     As Range
    Dim List    As Variant
    Dim Txt     As String
    
    Set Rng = Range("B1:B19")
    On Error Resume Next
    List = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(0, 0)
    If Err Then
        Txt = "There are no empty cells in" & vbCr & _
              "the examined range."
    Else
        Txt = "The following cells are empty." & vbCr & _
              Join(Split(List, ","), vbCr)
    End If
    MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Range " & Rng.Address(0, 0)
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

It uses Excel's own SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank), avoiding an error which must occur if this method returns nothing, and presenting the result in a legible format created by manipulating the range address if one is returned.

Answer (score 0):

### Find Blank Cells Using 'SpecialCells'

- The 2nd Sub (`listBlanks`) is the main Sub.
- The 1st Sub shows how to use the main Sub.
- The 3rd Sub shows how `SpecialCells` works, which on one hand might be considered
  unreliable or on the other hand could be used to one's advantage.
- After using the 3rd Sub, one could conclude that `SpecialCells` 'considers' only cells at the intersection of the `UsedRange` and the 'supplied' range.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testListBlanks()
    
    Const RangeAddress As String = "B1:B19"
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range(RangeAddress)
    
    listBlanks rng
    listBlanks rng, True

End Sub

Sub listBlanks(SourceRange As Range, _
               Optional useList As Boolean = False)
    Const proc As String = "'listBlanks'"
    
    On Error GoTo clearError
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = SourceRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Dim msgString As String
    
    GoSub writeMsg
    
    MsgBox msgString, vbInformation, "Blank Cells Found ('" & proc & "')"
    
    Exit Sub
    
writeMsg:
    msgString = "Blank Cells in Range '" & SourceRange.Address(False, False) _
              & "'" & vbLf & vbLf & "The cells in range '" _
              & rng.Address(False, False) & "' are blank."
    If useList Then GoSub writeList
    Return
    
writeList:
    Dim cel As Range, i As Long, CellList As String
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        CellList = CellList & vbLf & cel.Address(False, False)
    Next cel
    msgString = msgString & vbLf & vbLf _
              & "The range contains the following " & rng.Cells.Count _
              & " empty cells:" & vbLf & CellList
    Return

clearError:
    If Err.Number = 1004 And Err.Description = "No cells were found." Then
        MsgBox "No blank cells in range '" & SourceRange.Address(False, False) _
             & "' were found.", vbInformation, "No Blanks ('" & proc & "')"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred." & vbLf _
             & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description, _
               vbCritical, "Error in " & proc
    End If
    
End Sub


Sub testUsedRangeAndSpecialCells()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet2"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    With ws
        .Range("A:B").ClearContents
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = 2
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = 1
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(2, 2).Value = 2
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(2, 3).Value = 3
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(2, 3).ClearContents
        Debug.Print .UsedRange.Address
        .Cells(1, 2).ClearContents
        Debug.Print .Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address
        
        Dim rng As Range: Set rng = .Columns("C")
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "We know that all cells are blank in range '" _
              & rng.Address(False, False) & "', but 'SpecialCells' " _
              & "doesn't consider them since they are not part of 'UsedRange'."
            Debug.Print "No blank cells (not quite)"
        Else
            Debug.Print rng.Address
        End If
        On Error Goto 0
        
        .Cells(3, 4).Value = 4
        Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        Debug.Print rng.Address(False, False)
    
    End With

End Sub
```

**The result of the 3rd Sub (`testUsedRangeAndSpecialCells`)**

```
$A$1
$A$1
$A$1:$B$1
$A$1:$B$2
$A$1:$B$2
$A$1:$C$2
$A$1:$B$2
$B$1
$C:$C
No blank cells (not quite)
C1:C3
```

Answer (score 0):

**List blanks via dynamic arrays and spill range reference**

Using the new dynamic array possibilities of **Microsoft 365** (writing e.g. to target `C1:C?` in section `b)`)

```
    =$B$1:$B$19=""
```

and a so called ►**spill range** reference (as argument in the  function `Textjoin()`, vers. 2019+ in section `c)`)

```
    C1#      ' note the `#` suffix!
```

you could code as follows:

```
Sub TestSpillRange()
With Sheet1
'a) define range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B19")
'b) check empty cell condition and enter boolean values into spill range C1#
    .Range("C1").Formula2 = "=" & rng.Address & "="""""
'c) choose wanted values in spill range and connect them to result string
    Dim msg As Variant
    msg = Evaluate("TextJoin("","",true,if(C1#=true,""B""&row(C1#),""""))")
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Empty cells"
End With
End Sub
```